# Can golang hot swap in develop mode?

Tags: go

For production environment, I can accept that golang can not hot swap. But for development mode, must I recompile whole project, and restart server, even just modify 1 line of code? Is there any way to quickly hot swap code to check result for debugging?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use or create a watcher process that looks for changes, will recompile and restart the server when it identifies a change.

Here are some examples of this. I use Beego and `bee` rebuilds my server during development all the time.

**Gin**

- GitHub: https://github.com/codegangsta/gin

> `gin` is a simple command line utility for live-reloading Go web applications. Just run `gin` in your app directory and your web app will be served with `gin` as a proxy. `gin` will automatically recompile your code when it detects a change. Your app will be restarted the next time it receives an HTTP request.

**Fresh**

- GitHub: https://github.com/pilu/fresh

> Fresh will watch for file events, and every time you create/modify/delete a file it will build and restart the application. If go build returns an error, it will log it in the tmp folder.

Fresh works specifically with Traffic, Martini and gocraft/web.

**Beego bee**

The Beego web framework also does this. This is implemented in `bee`, a CLI tool for running Beego.

- Website: https://beego.me/
- Framework: https://github.com/astaxie/beego/
- CLI App: https://github.com/beego/bee

`bee` will watch all the project directories by default and has an option to also watch the `vendor` directory.

Comment: It still need a restart ?

Comment: Yes. A restart is technically necessary but can be automated as mentioned above. Go is a compiled language so the new source needs to be compiled. In practice, this is fast enough for Go that it's not an issue for development for me.